# ¿Cómo deshabilitar un botón que se encuentra en otra función?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

estoy con una aplicación en Javascript, HTML y CSS y me ha surgido un problemilla que no sé resolver. Tengo las dos funciones siguientes, la primera de ella al "pulsar" el botón "verBorradorBtn", muestra el contenido de la siguiente función (mostrarBorrador). El objetivo, es que una vez se accione el botón de la segunda función "checkResultadoBtn", se deshabiliten los dos botones, el botón "checkResultadoBtn" lo he conseguido deshabilitar, pero "verBorradorBtn" no. He probado a pasarlo como parámetro, pero no he sabido cómo hacerlo.

```
function mostrarUno(textoUno){
  $('#mostrarTextoAlumno').remove();
  if ($.cookie("alu")){
    var text=textoUno;
    var cadena = '<div id="mostrarTextoAlumno"><div class="box-blue" ><h4 style="color:white;">'+ text + '</h4></div>';
    cadena=cadena+'<div align="center" id="mostrarSolucion"><button style="color:white" type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalInstruccionesAlumno">Instrucciones</button>'
    cadena=cadena+'<button type="button" id="verBorradorBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Ver borrador</button></div></div>';
    $('#texto').append(cadena);

    var respuestaAlumnoC=[];

    $('#verBorradorBtn').on('click',function(){   

    mostrarBorrador(textoUno,respuestaAlumnoC);
    });
  }
}

function mostrarBorrador(textoEjercicio, respuestaAlumno){
  $('#mostrarSolucionAlumno').remove();
  if ($.cookie("alu")){
    var textoSolucionAlumno=textoEjercicio;
    var cadena= '<div align="center" id="mostrarSolucionAlumno"><h3 style="color:#F96161;" >Borrador de solución</h3>';
    cadena = cadena+'<div id="mostrarTextoAlumno" class="box-green"><h4 style="color:#F96161;">'+ textoSolucionAlumno + '</h4></div>';
    cadena=cadena+'<button type="button" id="checkResultadoBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Comprobar respuesta</button></div>';

    $('#borrador').append(cadena);

    $('#checkResultadoBtn').on('click',function(){
      rest.elegirRespuesta(respuestaAlumno);
      checkResultadoBtn.disabled = true;
      //deshabilitar boton verBorradorBtn
    });  
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has probado con **$('#verBorradorBtn').prop('disabled', true);**? Con meterlo debajo de **checkResultadoBtn.disabled = true;** debería de valerte.

Comment: Exacto, así es, muchas gracias por la ayuda